# how do i print first word from last line from a buffer using tcl script

Tags: tcl

i have buffer "showbuffer". i want to get the first word of the last line of the buffer. how to i do i get it using Tcl. I tried to use split

Showbuffer is

```
Local Time
 ----------
  Jan 10 14:46:09 2014
  1389345369 secs 905581000 nano secs since the Epoch

Thank you
```

I used to following command to split the buffer

```
  set splitBuff [split $showbuffer "\n"]
```

Now i want only 1389345369 secs 905581000 nano secs since the Epoch to print store in other buffer

Comment: I find your question hard to grok: the first word of the last line is "Thank", yet you seem to want the entire 3rd last line.

Comment: Is **Thank you** part of your `showbuffer`? In other word, is **1389345369 ...** the last line?

Comment: @HaiVu Thanks you is not part of show buffer

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the buffer is obtained with:

```
set lastLine [lindex [split $buffer "\n"] end]
```

The first word of that line is obtained with:

```
set firstWord [regexp -inline {\S+} $lastLine]
```

---

When dealing with lines, you may want to replace blank lines first:

```
# Apply the substitution in a loop until it doesn't match
while {[regsub -all {\n\s*\n} $buffer "\n" buffer]} {}
```

In general, you get the words with:

```
set words [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $theLine]
```

And then use `lindex` or `lassign` to pick the ones you want.

```
lassign $words seconds - nanosecs
puts "got $seconds and $nanosecs"
```

Comment: can i split the buffer after occurrence of particular word. Say i want to split the after the word "Local Time" and store the data after the Local Time. In some files "Local Time" may occur at 10th line and other file at 46th position.

Comment: @AustinPhilipD'silva Yes, but you didn't ask for that. (`lsearch` may be very helpful to find a particular line once you've split them.)

Comment: @DonalFellows- initially  i thought that Local Time occurs at common line number in buffer. But it seems to change. so the safest way is to split the buffer after "Local Time" to extract date and seconds from epoch

Comment: i used  
set  splitBuff [split $showbuffer "\n"]
set time [lindex $splitBuff 3]
to display time.

Comment: @AustinPhilipD'silva You know how your data works far better than I do!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract "M secs N nano secs form the Epoch" from the string no matter where it lies, you can:

```
set showbuffer {Local Time
 ----------
  Jan 10 14:46:09 2014
  1389345369 secs 905581000 nano secs since the Epoch

Thank you}

regexp {\d+ secs \d+ nano secs since the Epoch} $showbuffer result
puts $result
```

```
1389345369 secs 905581000 nano secs since the Epoch
```

Comment: above code can be used only if date and time is same every time but it keep changing on executuion